# MFC input form not accept less than 5 symbols

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have MFC dialog form with Text Edit control that allows to enter not more than 5 symbols. But how to make system not accept string less than 5 symbols?

Dialog form:

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(InputDialog, CDialogEx)



InputDialog::InputDialog(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(InputDialog::IDD, pParent)
    , m_edit(_T(""))
{
}

InputDialog::~InputDialog()
{
}

void InputDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{


    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);

    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT_INPUT, m_edit);
    DDV_MaxChars(pDX, m_edit, 5);
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(InputDialog, CDialogEx)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDOK, &InputDialog::OnBnClickedOk)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft provides the source to MFC so you can see how they implemented `DDV_MaxChars`. Simply copy it and change the condition.

```
void AFXAPI DDV_MinChars(CDataExchange* pDX, CString const& value, int nChars)
{
    // ...
    if (pDX->m_bSaveAndValidate && value.GetLength() < nChars)
    {
        // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle the Kill Focus event for the text field.  In the handler for the event get the length of the string that was entered.  If it's less than 5, optionally pop up a message, and, set the focus back to the field.

Comment: That's completely opposite to the philosophy of MFC dialogs, which do all their data validation when the dialog closes.

Comment: @MarkRansom I disagree. From a UX standpoint, it makes more sense to validate at the point when the data is entered.

Comment: Absolutely it depends on the type of application. But as the question is already using the MFC validation techniques it would be a disaster to mix in a second style of validation.

Comment: @MarkRansom Microsoft dialog validation is not perfect.  Especially in the case where a user enters many fields of data.  In your scenario, it may take several iterations to resolve the fields to correct values.  My users would not settle for that.

Comment: I'm absolutely not arguing with you. Even Microsoft has changed their approach in more modern platforms. I'm just saying it's a mistake to mix styles.